# Matrix of a nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In "Linear Algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler, the author states that there is a basis of V such that the representative matrix of a nilpotent operator is upper triangular, but with 0s on the diagonal.

The proof is basically:

- Choose a basis of null(T), then extend it to a basis of null(T^2), then...
- The columns corresponding to null(T) are all 0
- The next set of columns correspond to null(T^2), so they are in the span of the previous vector. ***Thus all nonzero entries lie above the diagonal***
- Continue in this fashion

(I summarized the proof. If it is not clear, I will provide more details)

I cannot understand why the fact that $null(T^k) \subseteq null(T^{k+1})$ implies that nonzero entries are above the diagonal (the part in bold italics font).

Comment: Hi I was reading your other question, but you deleted it before I had the chance to comment. The mental cache is definitely limited. The way to understand stuff is to understand each concept efficiently: for instance the definition of uniform continuity requires a lot of information i.e. for all $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ such that for all $x,y$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. So if you were not intuitive about what a uniform continuous function is it would very difficult to grasp a proof involving uniform functions.

Comment: I think when you find a proof too complicated is to try to see what makes the proof obscure. Try to break it down into simpler parts and try to save each part efficiently in your memory. And then after doing that see if the proof makes sense, if not repeat the procedure. It is useful to see how someone who says that understands the proof thinks about the proof. It is important to find the perpective to see things intuitively

Comment: Hi. What I wanted to get from the question was perspectives from other people, particularly people smarter than me (i.e. the majority of guys on this site), about the way they process abstract things, because self-observation can only go so far. I am somewhat pleased to find that not being able to put everything in my head on the fly is a common shortcoming.

Comment: I understand that by time and experience devoted to a subject, it can become clearer and maybe even intuitive. In fact, I was also hoping to speculate about the theoretical limits of this "getting used to things". By the way, I am very pleased that you took the time to reach me through comments in a different post. I deleted the question because of the instantaneous downvotes, expecting the trend to go on. I understand that such a question may be perceived as off-topic at first, but I believe it is deeply connected with mathematics.

Comment: Moreover, questions like "Can I use my powers for good?" Clearly show that there is room for a bit of philosophical debate in this site

Answer (score 2):

Considering a special case may clarify things. Say $T:V\to V$ where $V$ is a two-dimensional vector space. Say $T^2=0$. Say $v$ is a basis for $\ker T$ and $(v,u)$ is a basis for $\ker T^2=V$. Say the matrix for $T$ in this basis is $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $$Tv=av+cu$$ and $$Tu=bv+du.$$ But $Tv=0$, hence $a=c=0$. And $Tu\in\ker T$, so $Tu$ must be a multiple of $v$, hence $d=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the matrix of a linear map $T$ in the coordinate system of some basis $b_1,\cdots,b_n$, then $A_{ij}$ are the numbers such that $T(b_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij}b_i$. Therefore, $A$ is upper triangular if and only if $T(b_j)\in\operatorname{span}\{b_i\,:\, i\le j\}$ for all $j$ (this property goes by the name of "the basis is a flag for $T$"). And $A$ is strictly upper triangular if and only if $T(b_j)\in\operatorname{span}\{b_i\,:\,i<j\}$.

Therefore, a basis obtained by consecutive completion of $\ker T^m$ to $\ker T^{m+1}$ and ordered as such $$\underbrace{b_1^1,b_2^1,\cdots,b_{h_1}^1}_{\in\ker T},\underbrace{b_1^2,b_2^2,\cdots,b_{h_2}^2}_{\in\ker T^2\setminus\ker T},\cdots,\underbrace{b_1^u,b_2^u,\cdots,b_{h_u}^u}_{\in\ker T^u\setminus\ker T^{u-1}}$$ is always a "strict" flag for $T$: since $T(\ker T^k)\subseteq \ker T^{k-1}$, $T\left(b_j^{k}\right)\in\operatorname{span}\left\{b_v^{s}\,:\, s<k,\ v\le h_s\right\}$, which are vectors that strictly preceed $b^{k}_v$ in the ordering of the basis.